# WPF Datagrid programmatically added columns bind from list in class

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I have an `Employee` class:

```
class Employee
{
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SurName { get; set; }
        public int Rest{ get; set; }
        public int  Worked { get; set; }
        public List<int> PerShift= new List<int>(); 
}
```

In my database, I save how many times an employee worked in 1st shift how many in 2nd etc. Then in my datagrid, I want to see how many times each employee worked in total, how many days he rested and how many days he worked in each shift. The thing is that shift number is set by user, so I have to programmatically add those columns

```
<DataGrid Name="EmployeesStatsDatagrid"
          Grid.Row="1"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False"
          Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
          Grid.Column="0"
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
          CanUserDeleteRows="False"
          CanUserResizeRows="False"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Surname" Binding="{Binding SureName}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rest" Binding="{Binding Rest}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Δούλεψε" Binding="{Binding Worked}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Then I add the extra columns

```
for (int i = 0; i < Collections.ShiftsCollection.Count; i++)
{
    DataGridTextColumn textColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
    textColumn.Header = Collections.ShiftsCollection[i].ShiftName.ToUpper();
    //textColumn.Binding = new Binding(Collections.ShiftsCollection[i].ShiftName);
    EmployeesStatsDatagrid.Columns.Add(textColumn);
}
```

The columns are properly set, I create a list of `Employee`s and binding works for name, surname, worked and rest, but how can I bind the extra columns to the `List<int> PerShift`? Any ideas? Or should I implement it differently?

[image]

For example in this case I have two shifts, morning and afternoon, first employees PerShift list is {4,0} and second is {0,1} is there a way to have those values in the column binded? I hardcoded them in this case but if I sort columns values are lost.

Comment: Please try to describe the usage and a possible content of the `PerShift` list. Also try to explain how you want to visualize these list inside your data grid.

Comment: PerShift.count is equal to the number of shifts and hold the times employee worked in each shift! More details added

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't add two fields `Afternoon` and `Morning` instead of using a list?

Comment: It's because the shifts are added by user and i don't know how many there will be...

Comment: But typically only the three shifts morning, afternoon, night should be avaibable? Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ExpandoObject. Add your extra columns the same way you did, then create the DataGrid.ItemsSource object list as follows:

```
        var all_items = new List<object>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= MyData.Count-1; i++)
        {
            dynamic item = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
            item.Name = MyData[i].Name;
            item.Surname = MyData[i].Surname;
            item.Rest = MyData[i].Rest;
            item.Worked = MyData[i].Worked;
            
            for (int k = 0; k <= Collections.ShiftsCollection.Count - 1; k++)
            {
                item = ExtendExpando(item, Collections.ShiftsCollection[k].ShiftName, Collections.ShiftsCollection[k].Value);
                // or whatever corresponding value instead of Collections.ShiftsCollection[k].Value
            }

            all_items.Add(item);
        }

        EmployeesStatsDatagrid.ItemsSource = all_items;
```

Where ExtendExpando function can be implemented as follows:

```
public static object ExtendExpando(object OldExpandoObject, string NewProperty, object NewValue)
    {
        var ex = (IDictionary<string, object>)OldExpandoObject;
        ex.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(NewProperty, NewValue));
        dynamic output = ex;
        return output;
    }
```

Note: I successfully tested this code using Visual Basic not C#, you may need some minor modifications.